# remove duplicate element from groups (keep first 2) in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups Element Names
G1     A       1
G1     A       2
G1     A       3
G1     B       4
G1     B       5
G1     C       6
G1     C       7
G1     C       8
G1     C       9
G2     A       10
G2     A       11
G2     A       12
G4     D       13
G4     D       14
G4     D       15
G4     D       16
G4     E       17
```

And I wondered if someone know how can I keep only the **first 2 values** for each unique values in the column `Element`for each `Groups?`

I should then get something like:

```
Groups Element Names
G1     A       1
G1     A       2
G1     B       4
G1     B       5
G1     C       6
G1     C       7
G2     A       10
G2     A       11
G4     D       13
G4     D       14
G4     E       17
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `groupby` with `head`

```
out = df.groupby(['Groups','Element']).head(2)
Out[223]: 
   Groups Element  Names
0      G1       A      1
1      G1       A      2
3      G1       B      4
4      G1       B      5
5      G1       C      6
6      G1       C      7
9      G2       A     10
10     G2       A     11
12     G4       D     13
13     G4       D     14
16     G4       E     17
```